# MySQL Connector Python 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on

Tags: python, mysql, proxy, credentials, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to connect to SQL Databases using mysql-connector-python but I'm facing errors during login:

I feel it's related to an issue with proxy or credentials, I can connect SQL database using Windows softwares like Excel but when it's with mysql-connector-python I have different type of error I'll show you:

First database using windows credentials on Excel works but on mysql-connector-python I have this error:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    user="user_windows",
    password="password_windows",
    database="DDB_A"
)

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Second database using "database" credentials works with Excel too using different panel connection but with mysql-connector-python I have this error:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="X.X.X.X",
    user="user_database",
    password="password_database",
    database="DDB_B"
)

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

Answer (score 0):

check your user table；
select host,user from mysql.user;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the MySQL Service?

Go to Services from the Start Menu, and scroll down to find MySQL80 (assuming that the service name had not been changed during initial configuration) and start the service.